# tracy/tracy does not load any styles

Tags: php, debugging

I'm creating a small project from scratch and I have issues with making tracy/tracy package work properly. `Debugger::dump` works but without any styles, same with exceptions and errors.

index.php:

```
<?php

use App\Common\Config;
use Tracy\Debugger;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

Config::init();

$arr = [10, 20.2, true, null, 'hello'];

Debugger::dump($arr);
```

Config.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Common;

use Tracy\Debugger;

class Config
{
    public static function init(): void
    {
        self::initDebugger();
    }

    public static function initDebugger(): void
    {
        Debugger::enable(Debugger::Development);
        Debugger::$strictMode = true;
        Debugger::$dumpTheme = 'dark';
        Debugger::$showBar = false;
    }
}
```

nginx/conf.d/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

I already tried to change the nginx config as stated here https://tracy.nette.org/en/recipes

EDIT:

Downgrading to "tracy/tracy": "v2.10.x-dev" helped but now I cant for example interactivelly expand dumped array.